# MAC Address from Registry

Tags: c#, macos, networking, registry, guid

So I know what my MAC is, as I've looked it up on my routers config page. I've then searched the registry of my Win7 machine, went through all network adapters and there is some useful information, just not for me, since the "NetworkAddress" values are all empty. I've then tried using the cmd (getmac) and searched the registry for the GUID that was shown besides it (getmac showed me the same MAC address as my router) but all I've found was a similiar looking address. Correct format and length, but it's not my MAC address. I have already tried accessing it via self-written C# code, receiving the bytes, as it's a binary value, and converting it to string with the BitConverter class, but I still get the same address regedit shows me. My question is: Where do I find the MAC address? I'd like a writable location, but I guess any hint is good for the moment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why have you added the OS X tag?

Comment: You can get your MAC address by querying [Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217(v=vs.85).asp)

Answer (score 2):

`My question is: Where do I find the MAC address?`
If I am not wrong, you are looking for something like this

```
var list = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
            .Select(x => new
            {
                Name = x.Name,
                Type = x.NetworkInterfaceType,
                Address = BitConverter.ToString(x.GetPhysicalAddress().GetAddressBytes())
            }).ToList();
```